# Efficient way of extracting the last two digits of every element in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, binary

consider this sample:

```py
sample = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I need the fastest way possible of generating a list/array of the last 2 digits of the binary representation of each value in `sample`. This way I get the binary representation:

```py
bin_sample = [bin(x) for x in sample]
>>> ['0b0', '0b1', '0b10', '0b11']
```

I parse each of them like this and get the correct output:

```py
output = [bin(x)[-2:].replace('b','0') for x in sample]
>>> ['00', '01', '10', '11', '00']
```

The problem is that it is too slow, I'm handling large arrays, any suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT:
It takes around `5 seconds` to process `5 million` elements. I need it to take `~ 1 second`
EDIT #2: Any optimization that gains `~ 500%` speed increase is acceptable comparable to the previous algorithm.

Comment: _The problem is that it is too slow, I'm handling large arrays_ Can you elaborate? How slow is too slow?

Comment: @AMC edited with time info.

Comment: Time requirement without your hardware details is meaningless

Comment: @VictorDeleau you can extrapolate, I need an improvement in speed of approximately 500%, numbers are just to give context.

Comment: You need the last two bits as a string, like in the example you shared?

Comment: Well if you are running your code on a Raspberry Pi or something with a 800Mhz CPU, it's gonna run much slower than on an overclocked workstation with an 8700K for example.

Comment: @AMC, yes, the example is a working solution.

Comment: @Marcos I'll post a potential solution in 30s, can you benchmark it?

Comment: @AMC of course, thanks!

Comment: Switching to `str(bin(item))[2:]` will probably speed it up a fair bit. And only loop over it once, not twice

Comment: Can you share some context for this? I'm curious as to what this operation is used for.

Comment: `bin` (and related methods) works on one number, producing one string.  So you are stuck with iteration.  To do this with fast `numpy` compiled code you have to work with numeric methods, like modulus.  You are only generating 4 distinct strings, right?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, since 2 bits generate 4 posible values.

Comment: @AMC by the way it is used for hiding messages inside data, like images, audio, etc. One simple method of doing it is changing and encoding the last bits of each pixel. You can check out more in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

Comment: Are you doing anything after the operation that might slow you down?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes! I need to decode the hidden message from that list of bits.

Comment: @Marcos _yes! I need to decode the hidden message from that list of bits._ Are you also trying to optimize that?

Comment: @AMC we will see! Let u know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit-twiddling solution:

```
def pp():
    a64 = a.astype(np.int64)
    return (((a64&1)<<32)+((a64&2)>>1)+ord('0')*0x100000001).view('U2')
```

Lookup done right:

```
bits_map = np.array(['00', '01', '10', '11'])
def AMC_pp():
    return bits_map[a & 3]
```

Comment: @Marcos which in turn can be easily sped up replacing `%4` with `&3` gives a factor of 2-3 on my machine.

Comment: What is the `a.astype(np.int64)` for? Without it, the first method appears to be faster than mine by ~60 ms!

Comment: @PaulPanzer indeed, the second one is at least 2 times faster than @AMC!

Comment: @AMC Just a precaution. I seem to remember that on windows machines numpy ints default to int32 and I wasn't sure this gets promoted by the later operations.

Comment: @Marcos Yup, I found that the second one takes the runtime from ~160 ms down to ~60 ms, I added it to my benchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

### Quick benchmarks

#### Setup

```py
import numpy as np
test_arr = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, 10000000)
```

---

#### 1. Original solution

```py
def last_two_bits(arr_in):
    return [bin(num)[-2:].replace('b','0') for num in arr_in]
```

Time: **~5200 ms**

---

#### 2. [Solution by @aminrd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085777/11301900)

```py
bits_map = ['00','01','10','11']
def last_two_bits_nv(arr_in):
    return bits_map[arr_in % 4]

last_two_bits = np.vectorize(last_two_bits_nv)
```

Time: **~2600 ms**

---

#### 3. My tweaks to the solution by @aminrd

```py
bits_map = np.array(['00', '01', '10', '11'])
def last_two_bits(arr_in):
    return bits_map[arr_in % 4]
```

Time: **~170 ms**

---

#### 4. [First solution by @Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086044/11301900)

```py
def last_two_bits(arr_in):
    return (((arr_in & 1) << 32) + ((arr_in & 2) >> 1) + ord('0') * 0x100000001).view('U2')
```

Time: **~100 ms**

---

#### 5. [Optimized version of method 3, by Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086044/11301900)

```py
bits_map = np.array(['00', '01', '10', '11'])
def last_two_bits(arr_in):
    return bits_map[arr_in & 3]
```

Time: **~60 ms**

---

#### 6. [Solution by @Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086006/11301900)

```py
def last_two_bits(arr_in):
    output = np.empty((arr_in.size, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
    np.bitwise_and(arr_in >> 1, 1, out=output[:, 0], casting='unsafe')
    np.bitwise_and(arr_in, 1, out=output[:, 1], casting='unsafe')
    output += 48
    return output.view(dtype='S2').ravel()
```

Time: **~60 ms**

Comment: I'm seeing incorrect output for test case: `[28  3  1 13 14]` get's `['00', '11', '10', '10', '01']`. `13` is an odd number so it should go `01` not `10`.

Comment: @Marcos Fixed, I had the bits in the wrong order. Do you know of a good way of naming them, by the way?

Comment: thanks for trying, but this solution is `1.4` times slower than mine.

Comment: With a small sample like this, a plain list comprehension with `bin` is bound to be faster.  It's only on large samples that the array approach can shine.  Unfortunately that `join` `zip` is a list comprehension.  Getting the bits is probably fast enough.  The problem is combining them fast.

Comment: @Marcos I might have found a better solution.

Comment: AMC - you got it!

Comment: @AMC this is brilliant, the speed gain is way better than expected.

Comment: I added the code I used for the benchmarks to my post, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the last two bits in a binary representation, why not map elements into `['00','01','10','11']` based on `element % 4`.

```py
import numpy as np
sample = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

map_list = ['00','01','10','11']

def f(x):
    return map_list[x % 4]

f = np.vectorize(f)

output = f(sample)

#['00', '01', '10', '11', '00', '01', '10', '11', '00', '01', '10']
```

Comment: For a sample list of length `10000000`, this dropped time from 4.73 seconds to 2.1 seconds on my lapotp.

Comment: `np.vectorize` doesn't help with speed.  Fortunately, as @AMC shows, you can do this indexing directly on an array version of your `map_list`.

Comment: @aminrd still, thanks for helping, you almost had it!

Comment: Vectorize undoes all the benefit you just got from the indexing operation, which was already fully vectorized

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, hpauli mentioned that. Should I update my answer when another answer is already posted?!

Comment: @aminrd. You could always delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a benchmarking tool, but I wonder if this would help:

```
output = np.empty((sample.size, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
np.bitwise_and(sample >> 1, 1, out=output[:, 0], casting='unsafe')
np.bitwise_and(sample, 1, out=output[:, 1], casting='unsafe')
output += 48
output = output.view(dtype='S2').ravel()
```

Comment: I tried running this, it resulted in an error: _TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' output (typecode 'l') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'B') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''_

Comment: Seems to be ~60 ms, I'm running them again.

Comment: @AMC. So comparable to Pauls's optimized version? Wow. I didn't expect that.

Answer (score -1):

Using Numpy might provide a cleaner, faster solution, though I cannot attest to the degree of marginal performance boost you can gain.

```py
import numpy as np

sample = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
print([np.binary_repr(x, width=2)[-2:] for x in sample])
```

This returns the following output:

```py
['00', '01', '10', '11', '00']
```

Comment: `binary_repr` uses `bin`, with an added layer to ensure a width; that makes it slower.  On this small sample it times 2x longer.